# Title: Laravel and DataTables: Unable to Get Filtered Data in AJAX Request

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable

I have a Laravel controller with a method that filters data based on a date range. I am using DataTables to display the filtered data in a table on a Blade view. However, I am unable to get the filtered data when making an AJAX request. Here is my code:

```
public function filterDelegates(Request $request)
{
    $startDate = $request->get('startDate');
    $endDate = $request->get('endDate');

    $activation = TargetDelegate::withCount('orders as total_orders_count')
        ->withCount('delegateAssigns as total_pharmacies_count')
        ->orderBy('total_orders_count', 'desc');

    if ($startDate && $endDate) {
        $activation = $activation->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate]);
    }

    $activation->get();

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return Datatables::of($activation)
            ->addColumn('total_usd', function ($activation) {
                return $activation->getTotalUsdAttribute();
            })
            ->addColumn('total_iqd', function ($activation) {
                return $activation->getTotalIqdAttribute();
            })
            ->addColumn('total_pharmacies_count', function ($activation) {
                return $activation->total_pharmacies_count;
            })
            ->addColumn('formatted_date', function ($activation) {
                return Carbon::parse($activation->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
            })
            ->toJson();
    }

    return view('Target.filter-delegates', compact('activation'));
}
```

In my Blade view, I'm using DataTables to display the data:

```
<table id="cash-register-table" class="table">
    <!-- Table columns here -->
</table>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var table = $('#cash-register-table').DataTable({
            retrieve: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '{{ route('target.filter-delegates') }}',
                type: 'GET',
                data: function (d) {
                    d.startDate = $('#from-date').val();
                    d.endDate = $('#to-date').val();
                }
            },
            columns: [
                // Column definitions here
            ]
        });

        $(document).on('change', '#from-date, #to-date', filterDataTable);

        function filterDataTable() {
            table.clear().draw();
            table.ajax.reload();
        }
    });
</script>
```

When I select a date range and trigger the filterDataTable function, the AJAX request is sent to the filterDelegates method in my controller. However, I don't receive any filtered data in the DataTable. What am I missing?